# Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1

Tags: mysql, sql, etl

Estoy intentando hacer un bulk load pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1
```

Mi archivo fuente es un .csv como el siguiente:

```
YPERS;FNAIX;YSEXE
-201273163;;V
26712931;01-10-1998;V
41119417;01-01-1975;V
56560826;01-10-1985;V
```

El error me da en la primera linea. La tabla ha sido definda de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE #tabla
"(
  [YPERS]       INT        NOT NULL
, [FNAIX]       DATE                    
, [YSEXE]       CHAR       NOT NULL
)
"
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: Es MySQL o SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Builder in Talend ETL tool

Comment: ¿No es por el formato de fecha?

Comment: Si, formato de fecha estaba definido como ymd y es dmy. Gracias!